# Flutter UI ширина Container

Tags: flutter

У меня есть три виджета: Text, Container и Stack. Как сделать так чтобы ширина Containera была равна ширине Stacka, но когда Stack сжали меньше ширины Texta тогда Container должен остаться по ширине Texta?

```
Stack(
  children: [
    SingleChildScrollView( 
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: 
        Container(
          child: Text("...")
        ),
      ),
   ], 
)
```

Comment: Можете приложить пример кода? Не могу воспроизвести вашу проблему, чтобы решить ее.

Comment: @MiT Мне надо если ширина Stack меньше ширины Text, то скролл можно прокручивать, если больше, то нельзя прокручивать и ширина Container`а равна ширине Stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой вариант через `Positioned`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Text("START" + " Text Text Text " * 8 + "END"),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

---

Ширина `Container` ограничена шириной `SingleChildScrollView`. `SingleChildScrollView` берет максимальные размеры вычисляя размеры своего `child`.

---

Вариант с `ширина Containerа равна ширине Stack`. Через `LayoutBuilder` мы узнаем размеры которые мы можем использовать в `ConstrainedBox`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          child: LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (context, constraint) {
              return SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                child: ConstrainedBox(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: constraint.maxWidth),
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: Text("START" + " Text Text Text " * 8 + "END"),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `Если ширина Stack больше ширины Text, то ширина Containerа равна ширине Stack` - это не происходит. ширина Containera остается по ширине Text.

Comment: @Jedy я вам ниже в ответе объяснил почему так происходит. SingleChildScrollView ограничивает размер Container

Comment: ОК, тогда как мне получить результат который я хочу?

Comment: @Jedy добавил в ответ

Comment: Спасибо большое, а то я уже неделю думал, и чет не додумался вычислять ширину из constraints.